# What is the expected speed-up of using parallelization in C++ (not OpenMp, but <thread>)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

What is the expected *theoretical* speed-up of using parallelization in C++?

For example, say I have 2 cores, and 4 logical processors. If I use a fully optimized parallel program to execute some tasks for me using 4 threads working at maximum capacity, how much of a speed-up over the serial code can I expect? Twice as fast? Four times as fast?

Please provide a reference for your answer.

And please do not close this question as being too broad or not containing a code sample. Providing a code sample would defeat the purpose of the question, since I am in search of a general, theoretical answer that might be used in a sales pitch for parallel computing. I am NOT wondering about the particular efficiency of some particular piece of code.

Comment: I think this is going to vary hugely according to the application.

Comment: Look up Amdahl's law.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific number.

More practically, there is nothing in std::thread that has to impede linear scaling. And that translates to the real world. Using dozens of CPU cores is trivial with STD: thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit imposed by using `<thread>`. It creates OS threads so can scale linearly with how many cores you have.

Now for the question of real cores vs. logical processors (Hyperthreading, SMT) you might find https://superuser.com/a/279803/112292 interesting. There is also lots of other benchmarks out there.

SMT is generally good when it can hide memory latency. So the speedup of SMT you can gain is purely dependent on your application (is it compute heavy, is it memory heavy?) and the only way to find is benchmark.